# java.util.zip.ZipException Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have developed a project in the Eclipse IDE and as we all know that Android won't support the Eclipse IDE after this year so I have started shifting my project to Android Studio. I have successfully migrated the whole project from Eclipse to Android Studio but when I am launching the project its giving me an Error

```
java.util.zip.ZipException
```

I have gone through different question asked by the same tag but nothing worked and I m still facing the same issue. 
Currently in my project there are three sub projects working as a Library projects. 
**Project A** is independent and defined as Library Project and **Project B** is dependent on **Project A**  internally and it is also defined as a Library project. There is one more project but it is independant named as **Library Project**.

When I imported my project it automatically generated all the modules present and connected with my project. But my problem is that I can't figure out how to solve this issue.

Here is my apps build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':ProjectA')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-6.1.0.jar')
        }
```

Error:

> :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/payu/custombrowser/BuildConfig.class

Comment: You can remove this line `compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-6.1.0.jar')`, it is already included in `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Thanks for the comment but facing the same issue after removing that line.

Comment: Can you show more error output, not just an error class name?

Comment: here it is 

':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/payu/custombrowser/BuildConfig.class

Comment: have you resolve ?@salman

Comment: Hi @SalmanKhan, Do you get any solution? I've same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check `libs` folder in all projects for duplicates.
Also check your libraries have unique package name, looks like some of them has duplicate `com.payu.custombrowser`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, package name should be unique so check it. this solution might help you.